# How to Move certain elements of std::vector to a new index within the vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, standard-library

I am porting some old hand rolled array processing classes I wrote to now use the std library containers.  One method I am having trouble porting is what I call "ChangeRecordOrder" for lack of a better term.  I need a standard library replacement.

Its definition is:

```
template <class T>
void ChangeRecordOrder( std::vector<T> IN OUT &inputVector, 
                        uint newInsertIndex, 
                        std::vector<uint> IN const &indexesToMoveToNewIndex );
```

For example (Pseudo code):

```
MyVector<uint> = {0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90}
IndexesToMove = {2,4}
NewIndex = 6

After call to ChangeRecordOrder( MyVector, NewIndex, IndexesToMove ):

MyVector<uint> == {0,10,30,50,20,40,60,70,80,90}
```

Note that the elements at 2 and 4 (20 and 40), were moved to index 6 of the original vector (in front of 60).

Of course I would like to do this in place, and not use another temporary vector.  I also dont mind the requirement that the IndexesToMove vector needs to be sorted before calling.

I couldn't find an std lib algorithm for this.  The algorithm that I had before worked on the raw memory and did not use c++ move semantics.

Thank you!

Comment: I added a note after the pseudo code, hopefully that clears things up.  Left me know if not and I will try to clarify.

Comment: @ScottKemp This is quite a specific operation. You can achieve it with a series of `std::rotate`.

Comment: Actually, this can be done with a single std::stable_partition. Wether that is more efficient depends on the different sizes involved

Comment: @MooingDuck: Inplace? How?

Comment: @ScottKemp: I don't think any standard algorithm will give you an efficient solution, but you can some inspiration from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qH6sSOr-yk8 and here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWgDk-o-6ZE

Comment: @ScottKemp: "Note that the elements at 2 and 4 (20 and 40), were moved to index 6 of the original vector" They appear to be at index 5.

Comment: I just added a solution. Not sure why the other solutions use loops. I just use a single call of std::rotate and no loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above two examples had issues with different input (noted above).  I worked out the algorithm to handle the different cases and it passed my unit tests.  It can probably be improved for speed.

```
template <class CONTAINER_TYPE>
void ChangeRecordOrder( CONTAINER_TYPE IN OUT &values,
                        uint newIndex,
                        std::vector<uint> IN const &indexesToMove )
   {
   // Make a copy of the indexesToMove as we need to do fixups to them in certain cases    
   std::vector<uint> temporaryIndexes = indexesToMove;

   for ( uint i=0; i<temporaryIndexes.size(); i++ )
      {
      uint indexToMove = temporaryIndexes[i];

      if ( indexToMove < newIndex )
         {
         uint leftIndex  = indexToMove;
         uint rightIndex = newIndex -1;
         uint newFirst   = leftIndex + 1;
         std::rotate( values.begin() + leftIndex, values.begin() + newFirst,  values.begin() + rightIndex +1);

         // fix up indexes
         for( uint j=i+1; j<temporaryIndexes.size(); j++ )
            {
            uint &futureIndex = temporaryIndexes[j];
            if ( futureIndex > leftIndex && futureIndex <=rightIndex )
               --futureIndex;
            }
         }
      else if ( indexToMove > newIndex )
         {
         uint leftIndex  = newIndex;
         uint rightIndex = indexToMove;
         uint newFirst   = indexToMove;
         std::rotate( values.begin() + leftIndex, values.begin() + newFirst,  values.begin() + rightIndex +1);

         // fix up indexes
         for( uint j=i+1; j<temporaryIndexes.size(); j++ )
            {
            uint &futureIndex = temporaryIndexes[j];
            if ( futureIndex > leftIndex && futureIndex <=rightIndex )
               ++futureIndex;
            }

         ++newIndex;
         }

      }
   }
```

Comment: Keep in mind "the above two" are no longer what this answer refers to.

Answer (score 16):

```
template <typename t> void move(std::vector<t>& v, size_t oldIndex, size_t newIndex)
{
    if (oldIndex > newIndex)
        std::rotate(v.rend() - oldIndex - 1, v.rend() - oldIndex, v.rend() - newIndex);
    else        
        std::rotate(v.begin() + oldIndex, v.begin() + oldIndex + 1, v.begin() + newIndex + 1);
}
```

test: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c31007000b9eeba

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9  };  

    move(v, 1, 4);
    move(v, 4, 1);
    move(v, 3, 3);
}
```

output:

```
move 1 to 4:  3   [4]   5    6    7    8    9  
     result:  3    5    6    7   [4]   8    9  

move 4 to 1:  3    5    6    7   [4]   8    9  
     result:  3   [4]   5    6    7    8    9  

move 3 to 3:  3    4    5   [6]   7    8    9  
     result:  3    4    5   [6]   7    8    9
```

Comment: Very nice code, thank you a lot! it should be answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> values{0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90};
    std::vector<size_t> indexes_to_move{2,4};
    size_t destination_index = 6;
    if(destination_index > values.size()) throw std::runtime_error("Come on, bro.");

    for(auto const& val : values) std::cout << val << ',';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for(size_t _index = 0; _index < indexes_to_move.size(); _index++) {
        size_t index = indexes_to_move[indexes_to_move.size() - _index - 1]; //We need to iterate in reverse.
        if(index >= values.size()) throw std::runtime_error("We dun goofed.");
        if(index >= destination_index) throw std::runtime_error("We goofed in a different way.");

        std::rotate(values.begin() + index, values.begin() + index + 1, values.begin() + destination_index);
        destination_index--;
    }

    for(auto const& val : values) std::cout << val << ',';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This yields the following output, according to [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/kKiAoa):

```
0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,
0,10,30,50,20,40,60,70,80,90,
```

Comment: Just saying, that results in a lot more copying than what an ideal soltuion would do.

Comment: @MikeMB Perhaps you could educate us and provide a better solution.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: OK, I provided a different solution. You can decide for your own if it is better. I just wanted to point out a drawback of the provided solution.

Comment: @Xirema, thanks for your effort.  Your code also passed the given input, but fails with the following input:  Indexs To Move={5} destination_index = 1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, that moves each of the non-selected elements at most once:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<int> values{0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90};
    vector<size_t> IndexesToMove{2,4};
    size_t NewIndex = 6;
    //check that your indices are sorted, non-empty, in the correct range, etc.

    // move one element in front of the next element to move
    // then move those two elements in front of the next element to move
    // ...
    auto it_next = values.begin() + IndexesToMove.front();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < IndexesToMove.size() -1; i++) {
        auto it_first = it_next - i;
        it_next = values.begin() + IndexesToMove[i+1];
        rotate(it_first, it_first + i + 1 , it_next);
    }

    // move the collected elements at the target position
    rotate(it_next - IndexesToMove.size() + 1, it_next + 1, values.begin() + NewIndex);
}
```

Readability is admittedly not too good. It couldprobably be improved by better variable names and/or putting some of it into a separate function

Comment: thanks for the contribution, it passed the test with the given input, but the final rotate has range errors with the following input...

Indexs To Move={5}
NewIndex = 1